# Schur inequality

Tags: inequality, summation, symmetric-polynomials, muirhead-inequality

Show that for all positive real numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $abc=1$, the inequality $a+b+c+2a^4+2b^4+2c^4\ge \dfrac{3}{2}\left(a^2\left(\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)+b^2\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)+c^2\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}\right)\right)$ is true

I tried using Schur inequality which gave me $a+b+c+a^4+b^4+c^4\ge a^2\left(\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)+b^2\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)+c^2\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}\right)$. Then I wanted to show that $a^4+b^4+c^4\ge\dfrac{1}{2}\left(a^2\left(\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)+b^2\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)+c^2\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}\right)\right)$ but I'm not sure how to go about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^4+a^2bc)\geq\frac{3}{2}\sum_{cyc}a^3(b+c)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(4a^4-3a^3b-3a^3c+2a^2bc)\geq0$$ or
$$3\sum_{cyc}(a^4-a^3b-a^3c+a^2bc)+\sum_{cyc}(a^4-a^2bc)\geq0,$$ which is true by Schur and Muirhead.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add a condition on the product of $a$ $b$ and $c$

Comment: @Mike Druthe OK. Now it's true.

Comment: How do you apply Muirhead and Schur in this inequality ?

Comment: @Mike Druther $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^4-a^3b-a^3c+a^2bc)\geq0$ it's the Schur's inequality. Since $(4,0,0)\succ(2,1,1)$ we see that $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^4\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2bc$ is true by Muirhead.

Comment: Right I get it. Thank you !